# Mountain Lion Internet connectivity issue

Tags: macos, network, ethernet

I am system admin for my department I have recently updated all machines to Mountain lion and I am now getting reports of connection problems , the users lose their connection to the internet yet i can use ARD to successfully connect to the machine. We have done trace routes using terminal successfully.

If we reboot the machine the problem is then resolved. Has anyone experienced this issue and or have suggestions for possible permanent solution

thanks for your help
mcgrailm

mountain lion 10.8.4 Connected to Ethernet with Wifi disabled

the ethernet settings are manual and have double checked all the settings and cables. i change nothing and reboot the machine and magically have internet connection again

found that logging out and back in corrects the problem temporarily and creating and using another account resolves it completely but neither of these are an ideal solution its seems to be a problem within the user settings.

Comment: Please provide more info: OS X version ? Airport version ? I assume it is WiFi! what are settings for it ? Gave you -1 for lack of details in your question.

Comment: I stated that it was mountain lion and tagged with ethernet but I guess i needed to more precise. I disagree with your down vote I don't really think it's a bad question just not having enough detail

Comment: That is better now! do you have the Network settings ? any Error reports ? Do they loose Network connection or just Internet?

Comment: Remember, I am just trying to help you to get an answer to your question by providing relevant information, so nothing to be offended with.